# separate data in a column into multiple columns

Tags: r

I have some data which looks like:

```
    > head(d)
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
50 28 79  4  6 48  2 17  4 20
51 28 79  4  6 48  2 17  4 21
52 28 79  4  6 48  2 17  4 22
53 28 79  4  6 48  2 17  4 23
54 28 79  4  6 48  2 17  4 24
55 28 79  4  6 48  2 17  4 25
                                                                                                                                                V10
50 000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V
51 000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.5V000.8V000.8V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.6V
52 000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.6V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.7V000.7V000.8V
53 000.7V000.5V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.9V001.0V001.0V
54 000.8V000.5V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.7V001.2V001.2V001.0N000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.6V
55 000.5V000.5V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V
```

Where column `V10` is a large column separated by 24 V's and N's. The V's are "valid" observations and the N's are non-valid observations.

I want to separate the `V10` column. I tried using the following but it does not solve the N's problem.

```
sep_data <- df %>% 
  separate(V10, into = paste("x",1:24, sep = "_"), sep = "V")
```

Looking at the `tail()` of the `sep_data`:

```
          V1 V2 V3 V4    V5    x_1   x_2   x_3   x_4   x_5   x_6   x_7   x_8   x_9  x_10        x_11  x_12
174 28079008  6 48  2 17042 4002.0 001.1 000.6 000.4 000.4 000.4 000.4 000.5 000.7 000.9 000.7N000.5 000.5
175 28079008  6 48  2 17042 5000.7 000.5 000.4 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.4 000.5 000.6       000.5 000.5
176 28079008  6 48  2 17042 6000.4 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.4 000.5 000.6       000.5 000.4
177 28079008  6 48  2 17042 7000.3 000.3 000.2 000.2 000.2 000.2 000.2 000.3 000.4 000.5       000.4 000.4
178 28079008  6 48  2 17042 8000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.4 000.5 000.5       000.5 000.5
179 28079008  6 48  2 17042 9000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3       000.3 000.3
     x_13  x_14  x_15  x_16  x_17  x_18  x_19  x_20  x_21  x_22  x_23  x_24 nchar
174 000.4 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.6 000.6 000.6 000.6 000.7         145
175 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.6 000.6 000.6 000.6 000.5   145
176 000.4 000.4 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.4 000.4 000.3   145
177 000.4 000.4 000.4 000.4 000.4 000.5 000.5 000.6 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.4   145
178 000.4 000.4 000.4 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.4 000.4 000.4 000.4 000.4   145
179 000.4 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.3 000.4 000.5 000.5 000.5 000.6 000.5   145
```

I have `000.7N000.5`.

How can I use `separate()` to separate based on `V` OR `N`.

Data:

```
structure(list(V1 = c(28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28), V2 = c(79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79), V3 = c(4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8), V4 = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), V5 = c(48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 48, 48, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 
38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 
38, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48), V6 = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2), V7 = c(17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17), V8 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), V9 = c(20, 21, 
22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29), V10 = c("000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V", 
"000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.5V000.8V000.8V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.6V", 
"000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.6V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.7V000.7V000.8V", 
"000.7V000.5V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.9V001.0V001.0V", 
"000.8V000.5V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.7V001.2V001.2V001.0N000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.6V", 
"000.5V000.5V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V", 
"000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V", 
"000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V", 
"000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V", 
"000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.6V", 
"000.7V000.7V000.6V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V", 
"00003V00004V00002V00002V00001V00002V00004V00003V00005V00005V00005V00009V00011V00014V00014V00009V00008V00010V00011V00014V00011V00008V00009V00006V", 
"00005V00005V00003V00003V00002V00003V00009V00023V00069V00068V00008V00013V00010V00007V00012V00008V00007V00004V00006V00005V00007V00006V00004V00004V", 
"00002V00001V00002V00001V00001V00001V00003V00007V00018V00022V00042V00034V00021V00016V00018V00011V00009V00009V00014V00010V00010V00033V00083V00111V", 
"00098V00046V00016V00010V00005V00013V00052V00217V00337V00485V00138V00029V00026V00020V00019V00011V00006V00012V00012V00008V00010V00007V00005V00004V", 
"00002V00002V00001V00001V00001V00001V00002V00007V00013V00020V00012V00010V00010V00012V00009V00007V00006V00008V00010V00009V00010V00006V00004V00003V", 
"00002V00001V00001V00001V00001V00002V00003V00009V00014V00015V00013V00014V00018V00017V00010V00009V00010V00009V00006V00007V00008V00036V00061V00007V", 
"00005V00005V00002V00002V00002V00002V00003V00008V00055V00038V00020V00023V00022V00015V00017V00011V00007V00006V00009V00009V00015V00117V00082V00096V", 
"00046V00031V00047V00042V00037V00033V00040V00044V00067V00093V00053V00009V00006V00006V00006V00004V00003V00004V00020V00016V00010V00020V00049V00104V", 
"00088V00112V00055V00046V00013V00043V00023V00023V00040V00093V00046V00011V00007V00007V00007V00005V00008V00007V00010V00010V00025V00079V00059V00025V", 
"00028V00038V00022V00017V00018V00028V00049V00152V00116V00158V00087V00030V00024V00017V00018V00008V00008V00008V00010V00013V00012V00022V00072V00083V", 
"00060V00024V00032V00026V00014V00032V00078V00129V00199V00164V00107V00067V00052V00024V00012V00009V00015V00015V00036V00024V00019V00035V00056V00062V", 
"00020V00046V00042V00019V00003V00004V00020V00091V00159V00137V00121V00052V00045V00039V00008V00004V00005V00004V00008V00009V00004V00002V00009V00005V", 
"00070V00027V00026V00038V00020V00011V00016V00057V00073V00111V00053V00031V00018V00005V00003V00002V00002V00002V00010V00030V00033V00009V00005V00017V", 
"00033V00059V00042V00019V00018V00015V00017V00024V00036V00063V00026V00008V00005V00003V00003V00002V00003V00005V00005V00009V00009V00007V00005V00006V", 
"00009V00004V00001V00001V00002V00015V00012V00019V00031V00028V00013V00010V00008V00007V00004V00003V00003V00006V00017V00017V00014V00024V00012V00002V", 
"00002V00002V00003V00002V00001V00001V00002V00002V00009V00003V00004V00004V00006V00007V00010V00005V00004V00003V00003V00002V00002V00005V00067V00080V", 
"00063V00039V00025V00004V00003V00006V00015V00062V00144V00098V00079V00026V00017V00015V00007V00005V00004V00006V00004V00003V00003V00002V00003V00005V", 
"00004V00001V00001V00001V00001V00001V00002V00005V00011V00014V00013V00012V00013V00020V00014V00013V00008V00007V00007V00006V00007V00006V00003V00002V", 
"00002V00001V00001V00001V00001V00001V00002V00004V00008V00012V00025V00020V00026V00016V00017V00012V00011V00012V00017V00010V00012V00011V00006V00004V", 
"00003V00002V00002V00001V00001V00002V00008V00013V00013V00019V00022V00015V00019V00018V00015V00015V00010V00011V00016V00015V00012V00011V00007V00005V", 
"00003V00002V00002V00001V00001V00002V00004V00026V00145V00131V00027V00021V00020V00017V00019V00014V00011V00013V00012V00010V00007V00016V00025V00034V", 
"00004V00003V00003V00002V00002V00003V00007V00024V00022V00046V00013V00011V00012V00016V00019V00011V00010V00010V00018V00022V00039V00060V00051V00121V", 
"00085V00038V00024V00056V00039V00024V00022V00026V00040V00058V00041V00010V00010V00008V00013V00008V00008V00006V00013V00005V00004V00068V00079V00102V", 
"00081V00019V00005V00015V00008V00048V00114V00179V00240V00153N00031V00021V00024V00018V00013V00008V00004V00006V00010V00014V00009V00013V00010V00032V", 
"00018V00030V00006V00001V00001V00001V00003V00024V00038V00046V00024V00009V00010V00010V00006V00004V00004V00004V00004V00006V00004V00003V00002V00006V", 
"00003V00002V00002V00001V00001V00001V00002V00012V00021V00025V00027V00011V00009V00006V00007V00004V00006V00005V00006V00020V00008V00004V00003V00004V", 
"00002V00001V00001V00001V00001V00001V00002V00004V00007V00010V00011V00013V00013V00018V00010V00006V00005V00007V00010V00014V00016V00009V00006V00004V", 
"00003V00002V00001V00001V00001V00001V00003V00006V00009V00012V00011V00015V00019V00029V00022V00016V00010V00013V00009V00008V00012V00012V00017V00009V", 
"00009V00006V00003V00002V00003V00002V00003V00007V00007V00009V00010V00012V00011V00022V00013V00011V00011V00013V00019V00029V00022V00024V00037V00047V", 
"00074V00082V00059V00021V00003V00002V00001V00002V00002V00002V00003V00003V00003V00004V00007V00007V00004V00004V00005V00010V00007V00009V00005V00005V", 
"00025V00021V00010V00010V00008V00016V00032V00023V00023V00017V00013V00021V00024V00028V00027V00020V00020V00024V00029V00040V00048V00049V00043V00028V", 
"00027V00033V00035V00022V00026V00036V00048V00063V00065V00059V00022V00029V00025V00022V00029V00028V00021V00017V00018V00021V00031V00030V00024V00020V", 
"00012V00008V00008V00006V00005V00009V00018V00040V00059V00053V00063V00060V00044V00040V00043V00032V00029V00032V00052V00058V00071V00110V00128V00117V", 
"00097V00074V00058V00049V00043V00043V00052V00094V00127V00160V00091V00050V00043V00038V00040V00031V00021V00038V00046V00043V00050V00061V00050V00022V", 
"00017V00014V00019V00018V00008V00011V00014V00042V00050V00048V00027V00021V00019V00021V00016V00013V00016V00019V00028V00030V00034V00035V00021V00016V", 
"00010V00008V00007V00006V00007V00009V00015V00040V00058V00045V00034V00032V00039V00032V00023V00024V00029V00029V00033V00039V00068V00112V00096V00047V", 
"00030V00024V00018V00010V00010V00011V00019V00045V00071V00061V00050V00052V00049V00045V00046V00038V00027V00029V00041V00046V00073V00143V00131V00109V", 
"00065V00054V00063V00067V00060V00055V00060V00062V00067V00075V00068V00036V00026V00025V00028V00020V00016V00020V00044V00056V00062V00098V00127V00116V", 
"00091V00094V00079V00067V00040V00057V00056V00054V00054V00065V00059V00041V00027V00030V00026V00019V00023V00022V00032V00040V00060V00087V00079V00054V", 
"00047V00061V00057V00050V00049V00049V00056V00085V00074V00086V00084V00062V00058V00048V00047V00027V00026V00026V00036V00064V00085V00096V00117V00106V", 
"00084V00072V00062V00055V00042V00055V00066V00082V00099V00098V00096V00092V00089V00064V00045V00038V00036V00042V00075V00066V00066V00087V00088V00103V", 
"00092V00090V00074V00059V00046V00038V00051V00076V00092V00091V00097V00084V00084V00081V00033V00017V00020V00018V00031V00045V00038V00041V00038V00065V", 
"00113V00086V00082V00072V00059V00050V00050V00057V00058V00067V00072V00070V00061V00025V00009V00007V00010V00013V00028V00071V00084V00060V00044V00068V", 
"00090V00084V00070V00061V00053V00049V00041V00041V00041V00048V00043V00030V00021V00012V00011V00007V00007V00009V00013V00021V00034V00044V00040V00041V", 
"00057V00049V00015V00027V00032V00047V00041V00045V00046V00040V00034V00028V00023V00022V00009V00008V00007V00014V00033V00049V00056V00072V00039V00019V", 
"00021V00017V00013V00008V00007V00011V00015V00013V00027V00010V00012V00011V00016V00023V00031V00021V00020V00017V00017V00021V00035V00073V00130V00115V", 
"00102V00084V00071V00049V00041V00043V00045V00067V00083V00082V00083V00058V00048V00049V00028V00019V00015V00021V00025V00026V00033V00031V00042V00060V", 
"00025V00009V00006V00010V00006V00008V00016V00038V00054V00047V00038V00037V00040V00056V00041V00041V00027V00027V00029V00034V00049V00065V00024V00012V", 
"00010V00007V00004V00004V00003V00004V00010V00025V00041V00039V00051V00046V00051V00046V00046V00033V00031V00035V00040V00030V00036V00041V00035V00028V", 
"00020V00015V00013V00014V00012V00017V00032V00056V00051V00057V00052V00037V00040V00039V00038V00040V00033V00036V00047V00050V00044V00046V00038V00032V", 
"00021V00017V00015V00012V00010V00013V00024V00050V00101V00099V00053V00048V00043V00040V00044V00038V00035V00042V00043V00042V00040V00057V00060V00058V", 
"00036V00030V00028V00021V00020V00035V00049V00067V00058V00070V00042V00038V00044V00053V00050V00044V00039V00043V00054V00059V00082V00098V00116V00119V", 
"00101V00085V00076V00078V00066V00058V00054V00053V00049V00053V00058V00035V00033V00028V00032V00029V00027V00025V00047V00028V00049V00122V00135V00123V", 
"00113V00077V00040V00041V00050V00056V00074V00091V00113V00097N00068V00055V00059V00044V00037V00024V00020V00028V00045V00058V00070V00082V00084V00102V", 
"00082V00077V00044V00019V00012V00009V00029V00077V00084V00081V00051V00028V00031V00031V00022V00017V00014V00015V00015V00027V00037V00038V00020V00031V", 
"00019V00010V00010V00009V00006V00010V00019V00048V00068V00058V00047V00030V00022V00018V00017V00014V00019V00018V00026V00059V00031V00019V00017V00014V", 
"00009V00007V00003V00002V00002V00004V00008V00020V00030V00029V00024V00028V00028V00031V00022V00017V00016V00020V00028V00034V00039V00037V00029V00019V", 
"00012V00009V00005V00004V00003V00003V00010V00025V00037V00034V00027V00031V00036V00043V00040V00037V00035V00040V00031V00027V00039V00038V00038V00032V", 
"00031V00028V00022V00018V00021V00019V00021V00033V00036V00040V00041V00045V00040V00043V00039V00037V00041V00048V00053V00053V00052V00056V00055V00055V", 
"00050V00044V00047V00048V00030V00011V00008V00011V00012V00010V00008V00014V00011V00017V00031V00022V00009V00008V00018V00038V00040V00043V00033V00027V", 
"00004V00004V00004V00004V00003V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V", 
"00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00004V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00005V00005V00004V", 
"00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V00006V00006V00005V00005V00004V00005V00004V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00008V", 
"00006V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00004V00005V00008V00006V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00006V00006V00006V00005V", 
"00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00004V00004V", 
"00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00006V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00005V00005V00005V00006V00007V00008V00007V00005V", 
"00005V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00004V", 
"00004V00004V00005V00004V00005V00004V00004V00005V00006V00007V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V00005V", 
"00004V00004V00005V00005V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V00006V00006V00005V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V", 
"00004V00005V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V00006V00005V00005V00005V00006V00005V00004V00004V00005V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00005V00004V00004V00004V00005V00004V00005V00006V00006V00005V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00004V00005V00005V00005V00006V00005V00006V00006V00005V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00006V00007V00007V00006V00006V00005V00004V00004V00005V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00004V00004V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00004V00004V00005V00005V00005V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V", 
"00004V00005V00005V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00004V00005V00005V00004V00004V00005V00006V00006V", 
"00008V00007V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00007V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00004V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00004V", 
"00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00004V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V", 
"00004V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00007V", 
"00006V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00006V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00008V00011V", 
"00009V00006V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00007V00008V00006N00006V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00006V00006V00006V00006V00006V00006V00006V00006V00006V00006V00007V00006V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00007V00007V00007V00006V00006V00006V00006V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00006V00006V00006V00006V00006V", 
"00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V00005V", 
"000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.6V000.6V000.5V", 
"000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V", 
"000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.6V000.7V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.7V000.8V001.1V", 
"001.2V000.9V000.8V000.6V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.6V001.1V001.0V000.7V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.7V000.8V000.7V000.6V", 
"000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.6V000.6V000.5V000.4V", 
"000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.7V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.7V000.9V001.0V000.7V", 
"000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.7V000.8V000.6V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.7V000.7V000.7V", 
"000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.7V000.7V", 
"000.6V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V", 
"000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.7V000.8V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.7V000.9V000.7V", 
"000.7V000.5V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.7V000.8V000.6V000.6V000.7V000.7V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.7V000.7V000.6V", 
"000.6V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.7V000.7V000.6V000.6V000.5V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.6V000.7V000.7V", 
"000.7V000.7V000.7V000.8V000.8V000.7V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V", 
"000.6V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V", 
"000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V", 
"000.4V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.7V000.9V", 
"001.1V001.2V000.7V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.6V000.7V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.6V", 
"000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.7V000.5V000.4V", 
"000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V", 
"000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.4V000.6V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V", 
"000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.6V000.7V000.6V000.5V002.7V000.8V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V", 
"000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.8V000.8V", 
"000.8V000.8V000.7V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.9V001.8V", 
"002.0V001.1V000.6V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.7V000.9V000.7N000.5V000.5V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.6V000.6V000.6V000.7V", 
"000.7V000.5V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.6V000.6V000.6V000.5V", 
"000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.6V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.3V", 
"000.3V000.3V000.2V000.2V000.2V000.2V000.2V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V", 
"000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V000.4V", 
"000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.3V000.4V000.5V000.5V000.5V000.6V000.5V"
)), row.names = 50:179, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can I use separate() to separate based on V OR N? `sep = "V|N"`.

But I'd suggest pre-processing. Use `gsub` or `stringr::str_replace_all` to make the `N` entries `NA` *before* separating. Something like `df$V10 = gsub("N\\d+(\\.)?\\d+", "VNA", df$V10)`. Replace `NXXX.XX` with `VNA`, then splitting on `V` should leave `NA`s where the `N`s originally were.

Comment: huh, thanks! that was simple enough. How can I keep the `V` and `N` and not drop them? The `N`  observations are quite important since they are not valid and I would like to know which observations are not valid.

Comment: `separate` doesn't have an option to keep the separator. Instead, you could do another pre-processing step to add a separator. Replace all `"V"`s with `"_V"`, replace all `"N"`s with `"_N"`, then use `_` as your separator.

Comment: I'll also note that I get warnings about the number of pieces. This is because you have--as you say--24 Vs or Ns, but neither of them are leading or trailing so you have **25** pieces of data. Since you specify exactly 24 columns for `into`, the extra (last) piece on each line is dropped. You should probably specify 25 `into` columns, though only you can answer whether the first (or last) column is valid, depending whether the V or N corresponds to the preceding or following entry.

Comment: Thanks! The Vs and Ns are used as 0004V so the V is at the end of the data.

Comment: So definitely replace `V` with `V_` and `N` with `N_` so the letter stays with the correct number.

Comment: Thanks! one final question, why when I use `into = paste("x",1:24, sep = "_")` - I get a warning and when I change it to `into = paste("x",1:25, sep = "_")` it works without warning but creates an empty X_25 column?

Comment: Ah - I see. Your original data *does* end with V, so there are only 24 pieces. Remove the trailing `_` at the end. Perhaps a cleaner way would be to use `" "` or `"\t"` as the separator instead of `"_"`, and then `trimws()` will remove the trailing one for you.